# Vector drawable shown as full circle

Tags: android, svg, android-vectordrawable

I have a following vector drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="25dp"
    android:height="25dp"
    android:viewportWidth="25"
    android:viewportHeight="25">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:pathData="M12.5,25 C19.4035594,25 25,19.4035594 25,12.5 C25,5.59644063 19.4035594,0 12.5,0
C5.59644063,0 0,5.59644063 0,12.5 C0,19.4035594 5.59644063,25 12.5,25 Z M12.5,24
C18.8512746,24 24,18.8512746 24,12.5 C24,6.14872538 18.8512746,1 12.5,1
C6.14872538,1 1,6.14872538 1,12.5 C1,18.8512746 6.14872538,24 12.5,24 Z M16,6
C17.6568542,6 19,7.34226429 19,8.99878564 L19,16.0012144 C19,17.6573979
17.6534829,19 16,19 C14.3431458,19 13,17.6577357 13,16.0012144 L13,8.99878564
C13,7.34260206 14.3465171,6 16,6 Z M14,16.0012144 C14,17.1052262 14.8952058,18
16,18 C17.1026267,18 18,17.1036857 18,16.0012144 L18,8.99878564 C18,7.89477378
17.1047942,7 16,7 C14.8973733,7 14,7.89631432 14,8.99878564 L14,16.0012144 Z
M8.33473905,12.5 C8.14415114,12.3451212 7.57820716,11.8273213
7.57820716,11.8273213 C6.80306599,11.0695455 6,10.0347728 6,9 C6,7 7,6 9,6 C11,6
12,7 12,9 C12,10.0347728 11.196934,11.0695455 10.4217928,11.8273213
C10.4217928,11.8273213 9.85584886,12.3451212 9.66526095,12.5
C9.85584886,12.6548788 10.4217928,13.1726787 10.4217928,13.1726787
C11.196934,13.9304545 12,14.9652272 12,16 C12,18 11,19 9,19 C7,19 6,18 6,16
C6,14.9652272 6.80306599,13.9304545 7.57820716,13.1726787 C7.57820716,13.1726787
8.14415114,12.6548788 8.33473905,12.5 Z M9.03460423,12 C10.1996214,11.0532638
11,9.74316 11,9 C11,7.55228475 10.4477153,7 9,7 C7.55228475,7 7,7.55228475 7,9
C7,9.74316 7.86958707,11.0532638 9.03460423,12 L8.96539577,13
C7.80037862,13.9467362 7,15.25684 7,16 C7,17.4477153 7.55228475,18 9,18
C10.4477153,18 11,17.4477153 11,16 C11,15.25684 10.1304129,13.9467362
8.96539577,13 L9.03460423,12 Z" />
</vector>
```

On preview tab in Android Studio it looks like this (and this is what is needed):

[image]

but when I set it programmatically to ImageView as its source, with the code:

```
imageMenuItem.setImageResource(R.drawable.keno);
```

it looks like this:

[image]

The xml code for `ImageView` is simple:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_menu_item"
    style="@style/UpperItemsImageLeftMenu"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/leftmenu_keno"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/upper_item_image_dim_left_menu"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/upper_item_image_dim_left_menu"
     />
```

The dark grey is the background, set elsewhere. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: In my experience, Vector Drawables don't support the `evenOdd` fill-rule, so the paths need to be reoriented to appear correctly https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/fill-rule

Comment: @Duopixel is right to call out the fill-rule, although I'll add some more detail. VectorDrawable default fill-rule is "non-zero"; changing the fill rule was only introduced in API 24. So really you should stick to "non-zero" try to configure your vector graphics software to give you that.  Some links:
https://medium.com/@dineshbob10/the-mystery-of-the-disappearing-holes-a-gripping-tale-of-using-svg-in-android-442f6035a452#.hnq7fat30
https://blog.stylingandroid.com/vectordrawable-fill-windings/

Comment: @Duopixel @Lewis, you are right. I removed `android:fillType="evenOdd"` from xml and preview showed me the filled circle. Thank you very much! Too bad you didn't answer it, but comment it, since I can't set as the correct answer.

Comment: @DevetiPutnik, Just giving some hints rather than a full answer: your answer is great! 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so here is the solution.

**Source of the problem**

Problem is with this fill-rule in xml: `android:fillType="evenOdd"`. Android doesn't support this parameter until Nougat version, so we must somehow avoid it. As @LewisMcGeary pointed out, there is an excellent explanation on this topis on : [Marc Allison's blog](https://medium.com/@dineshbob10/the-mystery-of-the-disappearing-holes-a-gripping-tale-of-using-svg-in-android-442f6035a452#.hnq7fat30). More about this fill-rule can be found on [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/fill-rule) as suggested by @Duopixel.

**My solution**

I solved this problem by changing the software. I used this [online tool](http://a-student.github.io/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter.Web/) as suggested by before mentioned blog post with following settings:

[image]

and then I saved it to xml with following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:auto="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="NewApi"
    android:viewportWidth="25"
    auto:viewportWidth="25"
    android:viewportHeight="25"
    auto:viewportHeight="25"
    android:width="25dp"
    auto:width="25dp"
    android:height="25dp"
    auto:height="25dp">
    <path
        android:pathData="M12.5 25C19.40356 25 25 19.40356 25 12.5C25 5.596441 19.40356 0 12.5 0C5.596441 0 0 5.596441 0 12.5C0 19.40356 5.596441 25 12.5 25M16 6C17.65685 6 19 7.342264 19 8.998786L19 16.    00121C19 17.6574 17.65348 19 16 19C14.34315 19 13 17.65774 13 16.00121L13 8.998786C13 7.342602 14.34652 6 16 6M14 16.00121C14 17.10523 14.89521 18 16 18C17.10263 18 18 17.10369 18 16.00121L18 8.    998786C18 7.894774 17.10479 7 16 7C14.89737 7 14 7.896314 14 8.998786L14 16.00121M8.334739 12.5C8.144151 12.34512 7.578207 11.82732 7.578207 11.82732C6.803066 11.06955 6 10.03477 6 9C6 7 7 6 9 6C11     6 12 7 12 9C12 10.03477 11.19693 11.06955 10.42179 11.82732C10.42179 11.82732 9.855849 12.34512 9.665261 12.5C9.855849 12.65488 10.42179 13.17268 10.42179 13.17268C11.19693 13.93046 12 14.96523 12     16C12 18 11 19 9 19C7 19 6 18 6 16C6 14.96523 6.803066 13.93046 7.578207 13.17268C7.578207 13.17268 8.144151 12.65488 8.334739 12.5M9.034604 12C10.19962 11.05326 11 9.74316 11 9C11 7.552285 10.44771     7 9 7C7.552285 7 7 7.552285 7 9C7 9.74316 7.869587 11.05326 9.034604 12M8.965396 13C7.800378 13.94674 7 15.25684 7 16C7 17.44772 7.552285 18 9 18C10.44771 18 11 17.44772 11 16C11 15.25684 10.13041 13    .94674 8.965396 13M12.5 24C6.148726 24 1 18.85127 1 12.5C1 6.148726 6.148726 1 12.5 1C18.85127 1 24 6.148726 24 12.5C24 18.85127 18.85127 24 12.5 24"
        auto:pathData="M12.5 25C19.40356 25 25 19.40356 25 12.5C25 5.596441 19.40356 0 12.5 0C5.596441 0 0 5.596441 0 12.5C0 19.40356 5.596441 25 12.5 25M16 6C17.65685 6 19 7.342264 19 8.998786L19 16.    00121C19 17.6574 17.65348 19 16 19C14.34315 19 13 17.65774 13 16.00121L13 8.998786C13 7.342602 14.34652 6 16 6M14 16.00121C14 17.10523 14.89521 18 16 18C17.10263 18 18 17.10369 18 16.00121L18 8.    998786C18 7.894774 17.10479 7 16 7C14.89737 7 14 7.896314 14 8.998786L14 16.00121M8.334739 12.5C8.144151 12.34512 7.578207 11.82732 7.578207 11.82732C6.803066 11.06955 6 10.03477 6 9C6 7 7 6 9 6C11     6 12 7 12 9C12 10.03477 11.19693 11.06955 10.42179 11.82732C10.42179 11.82732 9.855849 12.34512 9.665261 12.5C9.855849 12.65488 10.42179 13.17268 10.42179 13.17268C11.19693 13.93046 12 14.96523 12     16C12 18 11 19 9 19C7 19 6 18 6 16C6 14.96523 6.803066 13.93046 7.578207 13.17268C7.578207 13.17268 8.144151 12.65488 8.334739 12.5M9.034604 12C10.19962 11.05326 11 9.74316 11 9C11 7.552285 10.44771     7 9 7C7.552285 7 7 7.552285 7 9C7 9.74316 7.869587 11.05326 9.034604 12M8.965396 13C7.800378 13.94674 7 15.25684 7 16C7 17.44772 7.552285 18 9 18C10.44771 18 11 17.44772 11 16C11 15.25684 10.13041 13    .94674 8.965396 13M12.5 24C6.148726 24 1 18.85127 1 12.5C1 6.148726 6.148726 1 12.5 1C18.85127 1 24 6.148726 24 12.5C24 18.85127 18.85127 24 12.5 24"
        android:fillColor="#ffffff"
        auto:fillColor="#ffffff" />
</vector>
```

I manually removed all `auto:xxx` tags and ended up with

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="NewApi"
    android:viewportWidth="25"
    android:viewportHeight="25"
    android:width="25dp"
    android:height="25dp"
    >
    <path
        android:pathData="M12.5 25C19.40356 25 25 19.40356 25 12.5C25 5.596441 19.40356 0 12.5 0C5.596441 0 0 5.596441 0 12.5C0 19.40356 5.596441 25 12.5 25M16 6C17.65685 6 19 7.342264 19 8.998786L19 16.00121C19 17.6574 17.65348 19 16 19C14.34315 19 13 17.65774 13 16.00121L13 8.998786C13 7.342602 14.34652 6 16 6M14 16.00121C14 17.10523 14.89521 18 16 18C17.10263 18 18 17.10369 18 16.00121L18 8.998786C18 7.894774 17.10479 7 16 7C14.89737 7 14 7.896314 14 8.998786L14 16.00121M8.334739 12.5C8.144151 12.34512 7.578207 11.82732 7.578207 11.82732C6.803066 11.06955 6 10.03477 6 9C6 7 7 6 9 6C11 6 12 7 12 9C12 10.03477 11.19693 11.06955 10.42179 11.82732C10.42179 11.82732 9.855849 12.34512 9.665261 12.5C9.855849 12.65488 10.42179 13.17268 10.42179 13.17268C11.19693 13.93046 12 14.96523 12 16C12 18 11 19 9 19C7 19 6 18 6 16C6 14.96523 6.803066 13.93046 7.578207 13.17268C7.578207 13.17268 8.144151 12.65488 8.334739 12.5M9.034604 12C10.19962 11.05326 11 9.74316 11 9C11 7.552285 10.44771 7 9 7C7.552285 7 7 7.552285 7 9C7 9.74316 7.869587 11.05326 9.034604 12M8.965396 13C7.800378 13.94674 7 15.25684 7 16C7 17.44772 7.552285 18 9 18C10.44771 18 11 17.44772 11 16C11 15.25684 10.13041 13.94674 8.965396 13M12.5 24C6.148726 24 1 18.85127 1 12.5C1 6.148726 6.148726 1 12.5 1C18.85127 1 24 6.148726 24 12.5C24 18.85127 18.85127 24 12.5 24"
        android:fillColor="#ffffff"
         />
</vector>
```

which is what I was looking for.

Comment: Actually `android:fillType="evenOdd"` is now supported for a few months : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70782765